# create tibble in R

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I want to create a tibble that contains these scraped films’ information ordered by their ranks. The column names are Rank, Poster, Movie, Year, Rating respectively. The weblink is https://www.imdb.com/search/title/?title_type=feature&num_votes=25000,&genres=horror&view=simple&sort=num_votes,desc
My code is

```
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)
link <- "https://www.imdb.com/search/title/?title_type=feature&num_votes=25000,&genres=horror&sort=user_rating,desc&view=simple&sort=user_rating"
horror <- read_html(link)
top50_horror <- horror %>%
  tibble(x = 50, y = 5,
         .name_repair = ~ c("Rank", "Poster", "Movie", "Year", "Rating"))
top50_horror
```

Can i get some help of creating he tibble from the web, and The column names are Rank, Poster, Movie, Year, Rating respectively, also the Rank column is of integers.

Answer (score 0):

Using selector gadget you can find out the classes where particular data is located, extract them separately and put them in a tibble.

```
library(rvest)

url <- 'https://www.imdb.com/search/title/?title_type=feature&num_votes=25000,&genres=horror&view=simple&sort=num_votes,desc'

webpage <- url %>% read_html()

webpage %>% 
  html_nodes('div.col-title span span a') %>%
  html_text() -> title

webpage %>%
  html_nodes('div.col-imdb-rating strong') %>%
  html_text() %>%
  trimws() %>%
  as.numeric() -> ratings

data <- tibble::tibble(rank = seq_along(title), title, ratings)
data

#    rank title             ratings
#   <int> <chr>               <dbl>
# 1     1 The Shining           8.4
# 2     2 Alien                 8.4
# 3     3 Psycho                8.5
# 4     4 World War Z           7  
# 5     5 Zombieland            7.6
# 6     6 Shaun of the Dead     7.9
# 7     7 Get Out               7.7
# 8     8 It                    7.3
# 9     9 The Conjuring         7.5
#10    10 Split                 7.3
# … with 40 more rows
```